# postgis not valid win 32 application

Tags: postgresql, windows-8, postgis-2.2

I'm trying to setup Postgres 9.5 on my local machine x64 based win 8.

I've downloaded postgresql-9.5.1-1-windows.exe and also downloaded postgis-bundle-pg95x64-setup-2.2.2-1.exe

Postgres runs fine, but when trying to install postgis at the end of the instalation (when installer is attempting to install sample database) I get this error:

ERROR:  could not load library "C:/PostgreSQLx86/9.5/lib/postgis-2.2.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I've tried with the x64 and x32 versions also as you might notice i tried to install it on a non-spaces path PostgreSQLx86.

Still no luck.

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: I'm having a similar error. I've installed PostgreSQL 11 x64 and PostGIS Bundle 2.5.2 x64 and when trying to create an extension in pgAdmin I get:
ERROR: could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.dll": %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
SQL state: XX000 I have Window 10 Pro x64. I have no idea where does this 32 error comes from. Have anyone experienced this or have an idea on what else to check? I'm stuck. Thanks

Comment: i used to similar error when i run pg_dum.exe 
that file is broken then i resolve by copy file pg_dump.exe from another PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sounds like you posibbly have a mix of 32 bit and a 64 bit versions of PostGres and PostGIS that are not mutually compatible with each other.

I find that the simplest way of installing Postgres with Postgis on Windows is to use the [Enterprise DB installer](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload).  Using this install tool it is a very simple matter to get it all up and running.  You can also easily add components after the install using the Enterprise DB stack builder tool.

Comment: Yeap, the problem was exactly that, first I installed a x86 version.Now I installed everything as x64 and passed without any problems. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help and welcome to GIS Stackechange!